# How to improve Gulp task performance with gulp-sass plugin?

Tags: javascript, sass, gulp, gulp-sass

I have a sass file with long loop (generate about 800 lines of CSS) that compiles about 25 seconds. It's too long.

How can I minimize compile time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is how I compile Sass using [gulp-sass](https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass) and it takes about 800ms or less. Are you sure you use the node version, not the Ruby [gulp-ruby-sass](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-ruby-sass)? Ruby is much slower than Node.js.

The loop may be the problem, be sure you are using Each or For, never While. But I also generated big grid system with a more less 200 selectors and it also was fast. Try my task config below:

```
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var gulpif = require('gulp-if');
var minify = require('gulp-minify-css');
var argv = require('yargs').argv;
var cache = require('gulp-cached');

// Values from console flags.
var is = {
    dev: argv.develop,
    prod: argv.production
};

// Gulpfile config.
var config = {
    sass: {
        src: './src/**/*.scss',
        dest: 'src/',
        maps: '/'
    }
};


gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src(config.sass.src)
        .pipe(cache('sass'))
        .pipe(gulpif(is.dev, sourcemaps.init()))
        .pipe(autoprefixer())
        .pipe(gulpif(is.prod, minify()))
        .pipe(gulpif(is.dev, sourcemaps.write(config.sass.maps)))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.sass.dest));
});
```